# Update the data in a div with ajax response

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

Here i wrote script in Ajax,its working fine But i have a small problem...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Jquery=jQuery.noConflict();
function filter(url1) {
    var data1 = "&id=10";
        try {
            Jquery.ajax({
               url: url1,
               type : 'post',
               data: data1,
               success: function(response){
                   if (response) {
                    //Jquery('html').html(response); 
                      //using this i can update entire page  
                    Jquery('.category-products').html(response); 
                      // Using this i can update particular div with complete response  
                   }
               }
               });
        }
        catch(e){ }
}
```

But my intention is to update that particular div with response of the same div.

Any ideas....

Comment: what do you mean by " response of the same div" ?

Comment: try using id instead of using class

Comment: Can you post your HTML ?  It would be easier to see what you are doing.

Comment: @MohammadAdil .... In ajax response i have the complete page right ... from that page i have a div with class name "category-products" i want update that div here Boss...

Comment: That way, you'll be adding response into the same document again.

Comment: If you use the inspector in your browser you can use `console.log(response);` in your code and then inspect all of the properties and their values to determine which one contains the html that is being returned.. Additionally what you're doing is verbose. Jquery has a load method that will allow you to achieve your goal in one line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the Solution for this....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var Jquery=jQuery.noConflict();
        function filter(url1) {
            var data1 = "&id=10";
                try {
                    Jquery.ajax({
                       url: url1,
                       type : 'post',
                       data: data1,
                       success: function(response){
                           if (response) {
                            //Jquery('html').html(response); 
                              //using this i can update entire page  
                            //Jquery('.category-products').html(response); 
                              // Using this i can update particular div with complete response
                             var string = Jquery('.category-products', response);
                             Jquery('.category-products').html(string);
                           }
                       }
                       });
                }
                catch(e){ }
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Var string = $('.category-products', response);

Then add string to your div.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
Jquery(response).find('.category-products').html(response);
```